# When to reveal what you saw using the Map card in Saboteur?

Tags: saboteur

When playing as a Digger, when is the best time to share the knowledge about one of the destination cards with the other players?

Should the digger tell other players this information immediately to avoid suspicion of being the saboteur? Or maybe it's better if he waits at least until the first saboteur is revealed?

What strategy should one use to take best advantage of the knowledge gained from looking at one of the destination cards?

Answer (score 6):

When I have just looked a destination card I often afterwards put a road card that either:

1. Obviously leads towards the destination card that I just looked at, or
2. Obviously leads away from that card.

It is then up to my fellow players to decide whether they trust my obvious move or not, based on whether they think I am a digger or a saboteur. I noticed that this is often enough information for the other players to understand what you have seen on the destination card.

I don't think there is a better way that does not render you suspicious. If you give too much information away at a certain point, people will always become sceptical. However if you let them infer the "right" information themselves, they might believe that you didn't intend to give all information. And people consider their own "discoveries" more credible than information that was chucked into their laps. Even if you planned it that way. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no clear answer to that.

If your group tends to be suspicious, no matter what you say, they will not believe it, doesn't matter what you say.

If you have been a saboteur before, the first reaction is not to trust what you say.

If you say something, and then somebody else checks the same card and says something different, usually it's assumed that the first person was lying. If the second person says the same, both can be saboteurs and the second is just following your lead.

If you had bad luck with your cards, and you have to discard, or to block something, even one of the less useful roads, you may be seen as saboteur and no one is going to believe you.

I can continue with more examples.

The final thought is, it depends on you and the group playing the game.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Digger, you always there to be more information out there. There is no reason not to immediately tell the truth if you are a Digger. It's true that not everyone will believe you immediately, but so what? If someone is skeptical of you just because you revealed information, they are not behaving rationally.

Therefore if one is a Saboteur, one should already know if you're going to tell the truth or lie and have a ready answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your group and induvial game but as a rule you should reveal this information as soon as you have it. If you are a digger you should tell the truth and if you are a saboteur you can chose to lie or tell the truth.

Giving the information right away is advantageous for several reasons

- If you find the gold you can know exactly where to go.
- If you don't find the gold but checked the top or bottom card you can narrow down the path you need to take.
- You can find a saboteur easier if they chose to block the path that the gold is said to be in.
- If another person gets a map card they can use it to confirm or deny what was said which can help and with multiple map cards you have a chance to confirm it.
- As a miner more information will help plan your actions allowing you to make the most of each card.

As a rule it is always best to get as much information out there as soon as possible but there are exceptions to this rule.